# Find difference between 2 strings in months

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve a problem where i need to find difference of number months between 2 strings

```
"January 2022"

"July 2022"

Answer=7
```

I looked all over internet to find answer but could not, mostly answer used datetime library

Is there any other way to solve this problem?

I tried to create a static dictionary like this but could not proceed further

```
m={
        1: "January",
        2: "February",
        3: "March",
        4: "April",
        5: "May",
        6: "June",
        7: "July",
        8: "August",
        9: "September",
        10: "October",
        11: "November",
        12: "December"
    }
```

Comment: you would need `for`-loop to compare strings with every value from dictionary. And when you convert `January` and `July` to numbers then you can substract these numbers. But if you will have different years then it will need more code - and maybe `datetime` can be simpler solution.

Comment: if you get only months then you should use dictionary `{"January": 1, ...}` to convert strings to numbers.

Answer (score 1):

At first I tried to use `datetime` modules but later if found much simpler way.

1. you reverse the dictionary to convert month to month id
2. convert year to month by mulitplying with 12.

```
month_ids = dict({
    "January":1,
    "February":2,
    "March":3,
    "April":4,
    "May":5,
    "June":6,
    "July":7,
    "August":8,
    "September":9,
    "October":10,
    "November":11,
    "December":12
    })

def to_months(month_year):
  month_name, year = month_year.strip().split()
  return (int(year) * 12) + month_ids[month_name.strip()]

print(to_months("July 2022") - to_months("January 2022"))
```

Note: As per above logic, the difference b/w July/January comes as 6 as this code does not include last month into count. As per your need, you can include +1 if need.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html):

```
from dateutil import parser, relativedelta

def delta_months(a, b):
    """ returns negative delta if b > a """
    a = parser.parse(a)
    b = parser.parse(b)
    delta = relativedelta.relativedelta(a, b)
    delta = delta.years * 12 + delta.months
    return delta

a = 'January 2022'
b = 'March 2022'
print(delta_months(a, b)) # -2
print(delta_months(b, a)) # 2
```